# How to populate form in jsp before submitting?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, jstl

I have the following jsp code:

```
    <c:url var="dep" value="depo">
        <c:param name="id" value="${account.id}"></c:param>
    </c:url>
```

I have the td: Deposit

When I click on the Deposit link, I want to populate form that will ask for amount to be deposited before submitting form to the controller for processing.

Something like

How do I do this? I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: jquery or javascript

Comment: Either go for using Bootstrap Modal with JQuery or if you want something vanilla, you wont get wrong here - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp